# How to test a data retrieval module?

Tags: python, database, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I am working on a project and have a data retrieval module written on python. All it does is build a query using string manipulations and then executes the query using another module (a connection module). I want to make unit tests properly. Does anyone have any recommendations on techniques? Is mocking a proper way to do so?

Comment: Hi there  Try one of these resources [Mocking in python](https://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python) and [How to write unit tests in python (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Lfv5tUGsn8)

Answer (score 1):

Your code consists of a computational part (building a query string) and an interactional part, where the actual communication with the data base is performed.  If these two are combined, the code looks as follows:

```
def fetchData(self):
    query = ... some string building logic here
    results = ... database access using query
```

In code like this, just to check the string building logic in unit-testing, you would mock the data base access (to avoid the dependency on the data base in your unit-tests for various reasons).  In the subsequent integration testing, you would then test the interaction of `fetchData` with the real data base.

An alternative approach is to extract the algorithmic part (the creation of the query string) into a separate method such that you can easily test this part independently.

```
def buildQuery(self):
    query = ... some string building logic here
    return query

def fetchData(self):
    query = self.buildQuery()
    results = ... database access using query
```

This makes your unit-testing simpler, because for the testing of `buildQuery` you don't need to do any mocking of the data base.  Again, in integration testing you would then test the interaction of `fetchData` with the real data base.